# Integration by parts on surfaces in weighted $L^2$ spaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, sobolev-spaces

I am on a closed and bounded surface $S$ without boundary.
Then it holds that
$$
\int_S \nabla f \cdot \nabla f  \mathrm dA = -\int_S f\Delta f  \mathrm dA.
$$
This is the $H^1(S)$ seminorm, meaning that I can express the $H^1(S)$ norm as
$$
\|f\|_1 =  \int_S f(1-\Delta) f  \mathrm dA.
$$

Imagine now I am on a weighted $L^2$ space with weight function $w$.

What can be said for
$
\|f\|_1^w
$?
The problem becomes to integrate
$$
\int_S w\nabla f \cdot \nabla f  \mathrm dA. 
$$
I tried to play around with various integration by parts, but I end up getting gradients of the weights and so on.
I see no reason why it shouldn't hold that
$$
\|f\|_1^w = \int_S wf(1-\Delta)f \mathrm dA. 
$$
Here $\mathrm d A$ is just the Lebesgue measure, so if one says that we are instead integrating against $\mathrm dW = w\mathrm d A$, then it just seems like it would hold, but I don't know.
Is it at all possible to rewrite in terms of only Laplacians?
$$
\int_S w \nabla f \cdot \nabla f \mathrm d A? 
$$

Comment: No. You need to take the gradient of $w$ into account, as you observed.